# closing a tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text-formatting

I'm trying to close a tag with javascript but when it writes to the document the forward slash is always missing. I've tried preceding it with a back slash ( "\/" ) but it does seem to help. I keep seeing `<pre>` on the page source. Here's the code:

```
var temp_index = 0,
    line_count = 0;
while (temp_index < text.length) {
    if ((text.charAt(temp_index) == "\n") && (line != line_count)) {
        if (line_count < line) line_count++;
        if (line_count == line) {
            text = text.substring(0, temp_index) + "<pre id='line'>" + text.substring(temp_index);
            temp_index++;
            while ((text.charAt(temp_index) != "\n") && (temp_index < text.length)) temp_index++;
            text = text.substring(0, temp_index - 1) + "<\pre>" + text.substring(temp_index);
        }
    }
    temp_index++;
}
return text;
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
Heres's the last line
<pre id='line'>Here's the current line</pre>
Here's the next line
Here's the final line
```

But I'm getting:

```
Here's the last line
<pre id='line'>Here's the current line
Here's the next line
Here's the final line</pre>
```

I made a quick fix by replacing the \n at the end of the line with the  tag.
Even though it fixes this problem, it causes bugs in the keyboard input. Here's the updated code.

```
if (line_count == line) {
    text = text.substring(0, temp_index) + "<pre id=\"line\">" + text.substring(temp_index);
    temp_index++;
    while ((text.charAt(temp_index) != "\n") && (temp_index < text.length)) temp_index++;
    text = text.substring(0, temp_index - 1) + "</pre>" + text.substring(temp_index);
    break;
}
```

Comment: yeah i just did, i'm still seeing < pre>

Comment: You don't need to escape a forward slash, so "//" actually equals "//". Backslashes are a different story though, so if you have "\\" in a string it will result in "\".

Comment: Not sure if your example is off or not, but you need to initialize `temp_index = 0;` and your `break` is not inside your `while` loop (you don't have curly braces)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: temp_index is initialized and I removed break. I updated the question to show my expected output

Comment: It might be helpful to include more code - the break for example indicates you have an outer loop or it won't run. If you don't want to look characters by character you could consider using `replace()` to find and replace the next occurrence of `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is syntactically correct - initializes `temp_index` and `text` and omits the `break` outside of a loop:

```
temp_index = 0;
text = "this is \n a test \n of some info";

text =  text.substring( 0, temp_index )
     + "<pre id=\"line\">"
     + text.substring( temp_index );

temp_index++;

while( ( text.charAt( temp_index ) != "\n" ) && ( temp_index < text.length ) ) temp_index++;

text = text.substring( 0, temp_index - 1 )
     + "</pre>"
     + text.substring( temp_index - 1 );

alert(text);
```

Results in

```
<pre id="line">this is</pre> 
 a test 
 of some info
```

You can also use `replace` to rewrite the current line and get the same result as above:

```
text = "this is \n a test \n of some info";
text = text.replace(/(.+?)\n/, "<pre id=\"line\">$1</pre>\n");
```

If you know the current line and want to prepend it with `<pre id=\"line\">` and append it with `</pre` I would use `split()` and `join()`:

```
// update line 2
line = 2;

// sample text
text = "this is\n"+
       "a test\n"+
       "of some info";

// split to an array on newlines
vals = text.split("\n");

// replace the second line, which has an index of 1 (or line-1)
vals[line-1] = "<pre id=\"line\">" + vals[line-1] + "</pre>";

// join back to an array using newlines
text = vals.join("\n");
```

Result:

```
this is
<pre id="line">a test</pre>
of some info
```

Comment: I updated the code to show the parent while loop and that I already initialized temp_index and line_count

Comment: does the `text` variable contain the current line?

Comment: it contains many lines, including the current. And the line to be highlighted is specified by 'line'

Comment: In that case I would probably just `split()` on `\n`, replace the array value of the current line, and then `join()`.

Comment: i just tried that, but it adds commas to the end of each line and removes all the \n's

Comment: i'm going to take another look at this tomorrow, when I've had some actual sleep

Comment: thanks. your code worked and replaced everything I had aforementioned( saved a lot of space ). All I had to do was add a \n to all the lines in the array except for the current, and then join them with a null seperator.